# Difference between two files view in HTML using Java or any jar

Tags: jar, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I want to write a script which compare two files in java and see there difference in html page ( side by side ), can someone help me out how to write ( where to start). I am pulling my hair out for this....

I want to use this script in beanshell postprocessor so that I can compare the standard output files with result files easily

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should be asking people for writing code for you here, consider hiring a freelancer instead.

Alternatively you can use the following approach:

1. Add [JSR223 Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) as a child of the request which you would like to fail if files won't be equal
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def file1 = new File('/path/to/file1')
   def file2 = new File('/path/to/file2')

   def file1Lines = file1.readLines('UTF-8')
   def file2Lines = file2.readLines('UTF-8')

   if (file1Lines.size() != file2Lines.size()) {
    AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
    AssertionResult.setFailureMessage('Files size is different, omitting line-by-line compare')
   } else {
    def differences = new StringBuilder()

    file1Lines.eachWithIndex {
     String file1Line, int number ->
      String file2Line = file2Lines.get(number)
     if (!file1Line.equals(file2Line)) {
      differences.append('Difference # ').append(number).append('. Expected: ')
       .append(file1Line).append('. Actual: ' + file2Line)
      differences.append(System.getProperty('line.separator'))
     }
    }

    if (differences.toString().length() > 0) {
     AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
     AssertionResult.setFailureMessage(differences.toString())
    }
   }
   ```

If there will be differences in files content you will see them listed one by one in the JSR223 Assertion

[image: JSR223 Assertion differences in files]

See [Scripting JMeter Assertions in Groovy - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, your information is so useful for me...
I didn't mean that someone will write code for me, I am new to Jmeter I dont know where to start the scripting in Jmeter exactly.So I created myself sometasks and trying out...